# Generic 5.0 bluetooth usb doesnt work at all with ubuntu

Tags: drivers, usb, bluetooth

Here's my problem. I bought a cheap usb 5.0 bluetooth to use with my xiaomy earbuds. I have dual boot windows, on windows 10 it is plug and play, the drivers are installed automatically and are ready to use, but on ubuntu, in any version that I have tested, 18.04, 19.10 or 20.04 I can't get it to work properly. In the terminal I can see that Ubuntu has detected the device, but for some strange reason the bluetooh is always off and I can't turn it on. I looked for all similar questions about this problem, tried everything suggested by the community, but nothing worked. Now here's something weird, I have an old 1.0 adapter that doesn't work with my headphones, but this bluetooth is working fine. I've been trying to solve this problem for a few months now, but so far nothing has worked. The bluetooth brand is that csr, cabridge silicon radio for both, 1.0 and 5.0 adapters. I am not an advanced linux user, but I am also not a beginner, I know how to execute some commands in terminal but I don't know how to make scripts, could someone help me?

---

As solicited an entry of lsblk on my terminal:
[lsblk with both dongles plugged in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3bdk.png)

also lsusb entry when both donngles are plugged in:
[lsusb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpNRQ.png)

---

dmesg | grep -i Cambridge and dmesg | grep -i Bluetooth  with no errors.
[dmesg | greep -i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9ZPQ.png)

---

[lsmod | grep -i blu & dpkg --status bluez | grep '^Version:'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wp6nc.png)

Comment: When connected what is it described as when you open a terminal and type `lsblk` please?

Comment: I edited the question, the entries you asked are there, thanks for reply by the way.

Comment: Try rebooting with them already plugged in, log in and then open a terminal and type `dmesg | grep -i Cambridge` and/or `dmesg | grep -i Bluetooth` and see if any errors are showing from your boot cycle.

Comment: Nops, no error, img add in the question. It seems to find only the 1.0 dongle, 
although the system sees the 5.0 dongle with "lsusb"

Comment: What is the result of `lsmod | grep -i blu` and also `dpkg --status bluez | grep '^Version:'` please.

Comment: Status posted on the question, sorry for the delay, had benig sick the last couple of days. Bluez installed, version 5.3 i gess and the ls mode gave the results showed in the picture, aways with both dongles 1.0 and 5,0 conected.

Comment: What if you run `blueman-applet` from the terminal and use the gui to toggle on and off?

Comment: Already did that, but I can reinstall blueman and show you, give the same result as bluez, doesn't see de dongle, I've even installed a custom btusb driver on the kernel and get the same result, already tried to reinstall ubuntu too but no luck, same thing happens. I don't know what it is, ubuntu sees the dongle but for some reason doesn't recognize it in order to use. Only the 1.0 works. Now do you understand why it is super strange? Tried on my other usb ports, tried on my laptop, always get the same result.